# AGAIN: how to hide subdirectories in browser bar with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Sorry to bother you perhaps again, but I can't get it working after trying at least 30 answers already given on this subject!!

I use a somewhat deep directory structure and the I would like to rewrite the address browser bar of all subdirectories been replaced by one: simply (www.)example.com/subdirname. Even if I redirect from within the subdirectories to a higher level.

In other words:
So I have: http://www.example.com/subdirname   ----> this what I would like to show **every time**. Here is also my main index.html located.
Then the structure beneath is e.g. www.example.com/subname/text/image/magazine/xxx.html

I have tried all the REWRITE CODES available (well, practically). But nothing works.
Can and will someone please give me the ultimate answer how to code this in htaccess? Please don't forget to tell me please, in which directory I should place this htaccess (allthough I tried all).
By the way, I don't care about SEO - the (sub-)pages don't have to be 'searchable'.
By the way, this is a site which I like to protect a little against theft, since it concerns my living of bookselling.

Thanks a lot beforehand!
Rokus

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect against, can you elaborate? There may be better ways to protect your work

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do this, a [frame redirect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Frame_redirects)

That'll always show the same URL in the address bar - but it's trivial to find the *actual* URL for anyone with the slightest bit of technical knowledge.

Users will also be unable to link to a specific page or magazine.

If you have intellectual property you want to protect, it might be worth looking into other, more suitable ways to do so.